# New to EJB world... Null pointer exception in EJB client

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb

I am learning EJB and I am trying to execute the Helloworld example given in EJB In Action book.

My app server is JBoss, I created the Jar file for the bean class and interface in the right directory( I can see the EJB in JMX console).

Now I created a simple client using EJB annotations, but I am getting a NullPointerException.

Here is my client code.

**Client code:**

```
package com.client;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import com.EJB.*;

public class HelloWorldClient {
 @EJB
 private static HelloWorldInterface HelloBean;

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  HelloBean.SayHelloWorldInEJB();
 }
}
```

**Bean class**

```
package com.EJB;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorldInterface {

 public void SayHelloWorldInEJB() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("Hello world from the world of EJB");

 }
}
```

**Interface**

```
package com.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Local;;

@Local
public interface HelloWorldInterface {
 public void SayHelloWorldInEJB();
}
```

Note: I tried using specifying the interface as Remote, it still didn't work.

Steps that I did so far to get to this point.
1) Created the file EJB files
2) Made the build.xml and deployed the EJB.

Am I missing any configuration files ???

Comment: Could you add your stacktrace, it will help others to understand and diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I created a simple client using EJB annotations, but I am getting a NullPointerException.

Your client code looks like an **[Application Client](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaay.html#bnabf)** and such client is supposed to be *deployed* on the app server and then executed in an **Application Client Container** (ACC) so that injection can occur. Starting the ACC requires an application server specific command.

The following wiki explains the usage of the ACC in JBoss (how to package, deploy and launch an ACC): [How to use an application client in JBoss-5](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowtouseanapplicationclientinJBoss-5).

If you don't want to use an **Application Client Container** and instead just run the application client class through a java command, injection won't be possible and you'll have to perform a JNDI lookup.

And in both cases, you'll have to provide and use a remote business interface for your bean.

#### Resources

- [How to use an application client in JBoss-5](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowtouseanapplicationclientinJBoss-5)
- [Creating and Running an Application Client on the GlassFish Server](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html)

#### Related questions

- [application-client](/questions/tagged/application-client)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The Application Client is _not_ deployed to the app server. I can see how the word "container" would make people think this is the case, but it is not. Please see the diagram and description at [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaay.html) and the first paragraph [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaku.html#scrolltoc).

Comment: I now see that I am wrong: I find that the Application Client _is_ deployed to the app server. But this doesn't make any sense to me. The first link I shared states that "An application client runs on a client machine", but how can we have that the application client runs on the client machine and is also deployed to the app server?! (I cannot remove my downvote until the answer is edited.)

Comment: p.s. I realized I was wrong when I checked the Glassfish admin console and saw that my application client was indeed "deployed" to the server.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to make two changes:

Replace the @EJB dependency injection with JNDI lookup. Dependency Injection is not supported for POJOs in EJB 3  (Don't know about EJB 3.1 though )

Then, the interface has to be a remote interface. The reason is that, the client here is a standalone java program - It would be running in JVM different from the web-app JVM.

Both dependency injection through @EJB and having the interface as @Local should work if the client was a servlet in the same server.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the OP is using an Application Client i.e. code that is supposed to run in an Application Client Container (ACC) and this makes injection of a private static EJB in the client possible.