# EJB 3 : Can't inject bean in client code, both of which are managed by the same container

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x, stateless-session-bean

```
@Local
public interface EJBA{
// declares a method 'validate'
}

@Stateless
public class EJBABean implements EJBA{
// implements the method 'validate'
}

class Model{
@EJB
private EJBA ejbA;
public void doSomething(){
   ejbA.validate();
}
}
```

Now, if I do the following from the execute method of a Struts 1.2 action class

```
new Model().validate();
```

**ejbA** of Model is null, resulting in a **NullPointerException**. The question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168920/new-to-ejb-world-null-pointer-exception-in-ejb-client) but, in my case, I am running the client code (Model) as well as the bean in the JBoss 6.1 Final server itself. The model and the EJB are in the a separate jar file and the the action classes are in a war file. Both of these are packaged inside an ear file.

If I use a context lookup  using **[ear-name]/EJBABean/local**, I am able to access it though. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Model` class is not managed by the container and therefore JBoss is not able to identify `ejbA` as an injected EJB. You have to turn your `Model` class into an EJB by annotating it with `@Stateless`/`@Stateful`/`@Singleton`.

That's why a JNDI lookup in which the container doesn't take part, works perfectly.